# store only date in database not time portion C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, sqldatatypes, entity-framework-6.1

I have a test class and an `ExecutionDate` property which stores only date but when we use `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` that also stores the time portion in database but I want only date portion.

```
public class Test
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
     public DateTime ExecutionDate { get; set; }      
}
```

Is any way to store only date on time portion in db using Entity Framework? Please help me....

I have added snapshot when use `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` that stores time portion 00:00 I want remove that

[image]

Comment: Well, what is the **datatype** of the column in your database table?? If the column in your database is `DATETIME` - then of course you get date & time stored. The **database column** must be of datatype `DATE` - not just your attribute on the C# class!

Comment: make your database column a `DATE` !

Comment: Thats more a viewing problem then a storing problem. A datetime is a datetime even if the time portion is set to nothing. Your tool that is showing the content of the table just shows the default format for datetime. If you don't want to see the timepart change the setting of the tool used for viewing db content.

Comment: You can only make it `DATE` on the database level - in .NET and Entity Framework, we don't have a specific "date-only" datatype. In .NET code, you *always* have date&time - can't change that. But in the SQL Server database table, you can make it a `DATE` and store the date only

Comment: How your database is created ? If you follow Code First and generate your database from your code then you must add Column(TypeName="date") attribute on that property.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think you are trying to specify database column type. You could use data annotations as described in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj591583) article.

Here is an example :

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="date")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

By default, string is translated to nvarchar, we have changed that here. Also Datetime (this is what you asked I suppose) which by default maps to datatime in sql server, is changed to `date` which stores only the date portion and not the time portion of a `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 4):

On EF core one may add override OnModelCreating in DbContext class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Test>().
                Property(p => p.ExecutionDate)
                .HasColumnType("date");
        }
```

Comment: Is this tied to a specific DB engine?

Answer (score 1):

As David said above, once you bring that data into the application it will be a DateTime with the timestamp added onto the date. This would be the same result too if you stored the date as a string and used Convert to change to a DateTime for any manipulation:

```
string date = "2015-11-17";
var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Unless you want to manipulate strings in your application to avoid the timestamp, you can only work with DateTime. For display purposes though, you can always format the date and remove the timestamp:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var formatDate = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6 now you have new special type - DateOnly

More info here:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24507
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-dateonly-and-timeonly-in-dotnet-6

Answer (score -2):

Change datatype on the database from `Datetime` to `Date` type

Is it really an issue for you anyway? You may want time in there at some point,

Comment: Any particular reason to downvote? HE want store DATE ONLY in database and there is a DATE type which does exactly that lol

Answer (score -3):

Change DateTime to nvarchar(10) in database 
if u use DateTime in database 00.00.00 will be automatically assigned by database

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
```